# Simple listing of google drive folders/files and show images with php

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am lost.

I am trying to show a list of folders, and files in my private drive account with php.
I have a ftp access to my webserver, but can only edit files and not install anything.

Is this even possible ?

Could someone help me with an example ?

I need this to show images in folders for family and friends with password to my site.
I know i can share folders with google drive, but this needs to blend in with my current images shared this way.

EDIT:
I am not looking for someone to do my work :) I am just looking for a help to get startet.. Just to get the connection to the drive folder and read an image.. I think this could also help a lot of other people struggeling with the same issues.

Comment: Have you made any code? stackoverflow is not a "write me all the code"-site, but a "help me with my code"-site

Comment: I have.. alot of diffrent examples have been tried, but i always end up more confused then before.. i am so lost...

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
  echo '<img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?id='.$file->id.'" />';
```